# Content Overflowing From Parent Background Photo container (responsive)

Tags: css

I have 3 columns of content (using bootstrap) that fit right into by background parent div.

When it is viewed on my desktop screen, it looks fine.

[image: desktop screen]

However, when I start shrinking the viewport size, the 3 columns naturally collapse to be one above the over, which is fine.

The problem arises where they are now outside the photo background div.

[image: mobile screen]

What is the proper way to deal with this situation, so that the column content still has a background to be overlaid upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into following snippet. Here I tried to simulate your case. You can try this on different viewport. It should solve your problem.

```css
.parent_img{
  background: url("http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.child_img{
  width:90%;
  height:20%;
  border:5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row parent_img">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="child_img" src="http://free-realestate.org/english/material/039.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="child_img" src="http://orig12.deviantart.net/d095/f/2015/149/3/e/mockingjay__fight_me_____5356____commission_by_artisticjoker-d8v7qfl.png"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img class="child_img" src="http://i949.photobucket.com/albums/ad340/Toki_Graphix/Other/CS%20Sketches/Mayet.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```